# Regex.Match not working for finding string contained in other text C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, macros, replace

I am using the following C# Regex call to find all instances of some macros that are placed in a text file:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(txt, @"/{macro:(.*?)}/");
```

but it is returning no matches everytime.  The txt string looks something like this:

> Hi, my name is {macro:name}

Any quick observations as to why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the `{` and `}`. These are special characters in regexes, used to denote a specific number of repetitions. So try this:

```
@"\{macro:(.*?)\}"
```

Answer (score 2):

`@"\{macro:(.*?)\}"` should work.